# SQL two consecutive dots between db and table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could somebody tell me the exact meaning of two consecutive dots below?

```
SELECT O.uid
FROM QAI..sysobjects O
```

This is for SQL-Server.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) two dots can be used instead of writing out default schema.

it would be the same as

```
SELECT O.uid
FROM QAI.dbo.sysobjects O
```